Getting an error accessing variables defined in a loop: cannot access local variable 'x' where it is not associated with a value
My code:
import numpy as np import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml') eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')

def eye_detector(): while True: ret, frame = cap.read()   

 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
      roi_gray = gray[y:y + w, x:x + w]
      roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
      eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray, 1.3, 5 )
      
      for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
          cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 5)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)    
    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):
        break

    elif x == 210 or y== 140:
        cv2.destroyWindow("frame")
        continue

    elif ey == 30 or ex == 50:
        cv2.destroyWindow("frame")
        continue
    
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


import project1_module1 
import project1_module2 
project1_module2.eye_detector() 

The error I get:
"cannot access local variable 'x' where it is not associated with a value"

I tried to redefine value inside the if() and for() loop but it didn't work. My expected result is that the camera has turned on and ended when the x, y, ex, and my values have scanned those values (lines 26-32 in project1_module2.py). But the error had occurred. (The code written above is project1_module2.py)

The definition of x (and y) in your for loop only happens if the loop executes a non-zero number of times.  If no faces were detected, the loop body never executes at all, and these variables never get assigned a value - yet you still try to use them later in the function.

All the variables you defined in the for loops control statements (x, y, w, h as well as, ex, ey, ew, eh in the inner loop) are only initialized if the loop executes at least one time.
In the case of the outer loop - if faces is empty because no faces were detected, x, y, w, h will not be defined.
Same goes to ex, ey, ew, eh in the inner loop if no eyes were detected (even if if there were any faces).
The meaning of the error you get is that you attempt to check the value of x although it was never initialized, probably because no faces were detected in the image.
You will get the same error for checking y (and also for checking ey and ex if your code will get to execute it).
You can solve it in 2 ways:

Change your conditions to first check that the respective collection is not empty. There are several ways to check if a list is empty in Python, one of them being using len:
if len(faces) > 0 and (x == 210 or y == 140) :
and respectively:
if len(eyes) > 0 and (ey == 30 or ex == 50) :
Note that this will work because and is short circuited and so if e.g. faces is empty the conditions for x and y will not be evaluated.
Initialize x,y etc. to some default value like -1 before the loops. This will ensure there are intialized even if the loops don't execute.

I personally prefer the first option.

The first option has worked! Thank you so much for your help fixing my code. But I also got another defining value error while defining "eyes" inside of a len(). So, do you think it's the same problem as defining the x and y values?

@jun Not sure I understand. I mentioned that if eyes in empty then ex,ey etc. will not be initialized, and my proposed solution included it. If the issue is different it would be great if you asked a new question (because a post here should be focused on one issue).

Ok, I'll looking forward to it.

Regarding the downvote: may I know why is my answer not useful ?

Ah, sorry, this is actually my first time using this slack overflow system so I 'm not really used to it, and the meaning of the signs. I tried to remove that voting thing but, it didn't work.

@jun it wasn't you who downvoted but sombody else ... you actually accepted the answer (accepting and voting is separate here). Only the asker can accept but any user with enough reputation can vote (up or down).

It is indeed very useful, well out of useful it is helpful. I'm sorry about the down vote you received.

No worries, it happens here every now and then ... I was just curious about the reason which is why I posted the comment above. Feel free to upvote when you have enough reputation ;-)

In that case I think this website definitely need a 'no attacking' or 'be kind' policy's something like that.
